# How can I access name of this objects

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here I have used object and I want to access its name and value and value. This is my code right now..

Here I have used object and in return code I have described name and value now I want to access value and name in my handleChange function tried several ways it is not working.

```
  
  const [location, setLocation] = React.useState({
    lifeLabs: "",
    gamma: "",
    hamilton: "",
    joseph: "",
    other:"",
  });
  

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { location } = e.target;
    setLocation(location);
  };
```

Here I tried changing the handleChange function using if statement but it did not work.

And this is the return code here I want to access its name and value.

```
<FormControlLabel
                    value="Life Labs"
                    name="lifeLabs"
                    control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
                    label="Life Labs"
                  />
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="Gamma"
                    name="gamma"
                    control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
                    label="Gamma Dyna-care"
                  />
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="Hamilton"
                    name="hamilton"
                    control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
                    label="Hamilton Health Science"
                  />
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="Joseph"
                    name="joseph"
                    control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
                    label="St Joseph"
                  />
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="Other"
                    name="other"
                    control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
                    label="Other"
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `e.target.value`

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
const { location } = e.target.value;
setLocation(location);
```

};

Comment: `e.target.value` does not contain a property `location`

Comment: I did't get what you meant @RubenSmn. It's using ES6 Destructuring. We will get the value from the selected FormControlLabel, When the user select any of the FormControlLabel, we will get the value with `e.target.value`, then storing the value as "location", and after that `setLocation` method uses the value in location.

Comment: `e.target.value` is of type `string` so you can't destructure it

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setLocation({ location, [name]: value });
};
```

Comment: Hello brother can you explain me this part please `setLocation({ location, [name]: value });`

Comment: Sure!  handleChange - takes an event as its input. and name and value, these variables are being pulled out of the event's target, which is an element on a web page that triggered the event. and setLocation({ location, [name]: value }); is using the setLocation function to update the state of the location. It's creating a new object that contains the original location object and adding a new property to it, did u understand now?

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleChange` function, you are destructuring `location` from `e.target` object. But `e.target` is radio button itself and does not contain `location` property. Instead `location` is present on `value` or `name` subproperty of `e.target`.

By looking at your code it seems like your `FormControlLabel` and state, appropriate way to set location might be

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setLocation({ ...location, [name]: value});
 };
```

- As setState is immutable, we can't update the state, so we use spread operator to retain previous values of location object
- For `[name]: value`, In Javascript, when you create an object literal {} and you wrap the object’s key in array brackets [key] you can dynamically set that key. For reference - https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/understanding-this-setstate-name-value-a5ef7b4ea2b4